# Emacs Init File Line Numbering

Tags: emacs, line

I am trying to display line numbers in emacs on the left hand side. I know it is the linum-mode. When I do `M-x linum-mode`, my emacs can't find linum-mode. It only finds `line-numbers-mode` which displays it on the mode bar at the bottom. Why does it not have `linum-mode`?

Also, when I put `(menu-bar-mode t)` or even `(menu-bar-mode 1)`, the menu bar does not start at start-up.

When I put `(global-linum-mode t)` I get the following init error (using `--debug-init`):

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function global-linum-mode)
  (global-linum-mode t)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/Users/nayef/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 68
  load-with-code-conversion("/Users/nayef/.emacs.d/init.el" "/Users/nayef/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("/Users/nayef/.emacs.d/init" t t)
```

This is extremely extremely frustrating. It works on one computer over SSH but when I do it on my laptop it does not work. I am starting to understand that even though Emacs is more powerful than VIM, VIM is at least 10 times easier to use, less keystrokes and requires WAY less modifications.

Comment: if I may advice.. Since you are on your laptop, its better to upgrade to latest version so that you don't need to install package separately and 22.1.1 is ancient.

Comment: I will just do that. Thanks @kindahero

Answer (score 2):

Which version of Emacs do you have?  linum-mode is included with Emacs 23 and Emacs 24.  If you can, you should probably upgrade to those version.  If you can't upgrade and you have Emacs 22, you'll need to do the following steps:

1. Download linum.el on your system (let's say it's in `/home/nayefc/`).
2. Add the line `(add-to-list 'load-path "/home/nayefc/")` to your .emacs
3. Add the line `(require 'linum)` to your .emacs

Restart Emacs, and you should be able to call `M-x linum-mode`.  Good luck.

Vincent.

Answer (score 0):

You're having problems because `linum-mode` is not a standard part of any Emacs distribution; it has to be installed. You can get it [here.](http://web.student.tuwien.ac.at/~e0225855/linum/linum.html)

Comment: This doesn't work. Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable bplist00\321)  when I require 'linum in init.el

Comment: You should put the folder where you've copied `linum.el` on the `load-path` first.

Comment: `linum-mode` certainly is a standard part of Emacs these days (since version 23, as gnuvince says; you can check the relevant NEWS file to find out about new modes, etc).

Comment: Is cc-mode also part of version 23?